# How to generate same encryption key in C# code and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, encryption

I am using AES256 for encryption within C# code and generating a key using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Pwd, saltbytes)` with fixed pwd and saltbytes. I have to do the same encryption process separately on already existing data in my database. Is it possible for SQL Server encryption functions (`AES256`) to generate the same key as in C# code? I wanted to stick to key generation in C# code. Although, willing to amend my process if this doesn't work out.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you looking for information on CLR procedures? Is this adequate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: I havent done any SQLCRL implementation yet, encryption in C# code is via plain C# methods, in SQL server I want to encrypt with same key.

Comment: Why do hashing in both places? You should just pick either c# or sql and do it all in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a single DLL that can be used by your C# code and from within SQL server as a CLR:
The following code was taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094(v=sql.105).aspx

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server; 

public class StoredProcedures 
{
   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
   public static void HelloWorld()
   {
      SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Hello world! It's now " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString()+"\n");
      using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) 
      {
         connection.Open();
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductNumber FROM ProductMaster", connection);
         SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         SqlContext.Pipe.Send(reader);
      }
   }
}
```

You can, of course, change this function to perform encryption-related tasks instead of Hello, World. The same DLL could be installed within SQL Server, or called directly from other C# executables.

Code to install and run the procedure in SQL might look like this also taken from the same MSDN page:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyFirstUdp FROM 'C:\Programming\MyFirstUdp.dll'
CREATE PROCEDURE HelloWorld
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyFirstUdp.StoredProcedures.HelloWorld
EXEC HelloWorld
```

Comment: but what if i have a return type in the methods used in C# code, how is that gonna work out for SQL server?

Comment: SQL functions can have return values. If you need help understanding them, ask a more specific question.